# Is there a function that returns the class const names

Tags: c#

Is there any way to read the const names into a list?

Example Code

```
public static class Cars
{
    public const int Length= 10;
    public const int Height= 15;
    public const int Weight = 20;
}
```

Comment: there is no methods inside `Cars`, only fields

Comment: More importantly, _why_ would you want to do that? You're probably trying to solve a problem from the wrong angle.

Comment: I have edited the question.

I only have these Class to get information from and need to get a list of this const names and the value, to show on screen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection like this.

```
var fields = typeof(Cars)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Select(f => new { Name = f.Name, Value = f.GetValue(null) })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Looks like you were a few seconds faster with typing ;-)

Comment: Wow, the answer was almost the same and you write it at the same time :) Great work both of you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
typeof(Cars).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Select(m => m.Name)
```